# How to test a void method using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

the below posted method in the code section returns void. I want to know how to test a method that returns void.
I checked some answers but the use "doThrow()" with passing an exception, but in my case the method does not throw any exception

please let me know how can I test a method returns void?

**code**

```
public void setImageOnImageView(RequestCreator requestCreator, ImageView imgView) {
    requestCreator.into(imgView);
}
```

**testing**:

```
public class ValidationTest {
    @Mock
    private Context mCtx = null;
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mCtx = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull("Context is not null", mCtx);
    }

    @Test
    public void setImageOnImageView() throws Exception {
        Uri mockUri = mock(Uri.class);
        RequestCreator requestCreator = Picasso.with(mCtx).load(mockUri);
        RequestCreator spyRequestCreator = spy(requestCreator);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mCtx);
        ImageView spyImageView = spy(imageView);

        doThrow().when(spyRequestCreator).into(spyImageView);
        //spyRequestCreator.into(spyImageView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to test? Is that test that "when `setImageOnImageView(RequestCreator, ImageView)` is called, it invokes `RequestCreator.into(ImageView)`"?

If that's what you're trying to test, you aren't wanting to test that it "returns void". Rather, I would recommend something like:

```
@Test
public void itInvokesRequestCreatorIntoOnProvidedImageView() {
    RequestCreator creator = mock(RequestCreator.class);
    ImageView imageView = mock(ImageView.class);

    setImageOnImageView(creator, imageView);
    verify(creator).into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: thanks, now it works. would you please have a look at my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267298/method-not-mocked-using-spy    i am trying to test a method but the test case fails

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify a void method is not throwing anything, then you can use the assertDoesNotThrows method as follow

> Assert that execution of the supplied executable does not throw any kind of exception.
> Usage Note
> Although any exception thrown from a test method will cause the test to fail, there are certain use cases where it can be beneficial to explicitly assert that an exception is not thrown for a given code block within a test method.

```
 Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() -> testCl.voidM("test"...));
```

If you have some dependencies in your class then you can use verify to check whether that dependency is invoked or not.